# Existing Git repository with files in mixed encodings

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8, repository, windows-1252

I have an existing repository with files in mixed encodings - some files are in UTF-8 and some are in ANSI (e.g. Windows-1252). Mostly everything works fine, except that I am getting tired of seeing "invalid characters" when performing a diff on the ANSI files, and I am particularly annoyed that I can't use my GUI tool to stage or unstage hunks with these characters. I am looking for a way to convince Git that a certain file uses a non-UTF-8 encoding so that Git would perform the conversion first and then do its magic against that.

As far as I can tell, there are two ways of achieving the result:

#### Custom binary-to-text filter

1. Add a conversion filter to my .gitconfig:

```
    [diff "win1252"]
    textconv = "iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8"
```

2. In `.gitattributes`, mark the file as binary and request this filter to be used to convert it to text:

```
    *.txt    diff=win1252
```

This approach seems to work fine in an isolated `git diff`, but I have encountered several issues which I don't know how to solve:

1. Even with `core.autocrlf = true`, this approach will not perform CRLF conversion on the output of the conversion command, so my diff will show end-of-line differences in changed lines. I can create a script which would run iconv to perform the encoding conversion, then pass the output to dos2unix which would perform EOL conversion, but it seems rather heavy-handed.
2. As the external tool is used very frequently, I experience significant slowdowns.
3. It seems that both command line and my GUI (SourceTree) do not respect the transformation settings when staging. `git add -p` shows garbage (even worse than the "unknown characters") and SourceTree stops the staging with an error message that it can't find the original text.

While I might be able to learn to live with #1 and #2, #3 is a blocking problem because I mostly need this conversions done to facilitate staging of hunks with the "unknown characters" in them. My current workflow, where I use `git add -p` without any conversions, might display "unknown characters", but at least it works.

A change to the GUI in impractical: all other GUIs I tried have much more serious problems than this.

#### Using the working-tree-encoding attribute

1. In `.gitattributes`, mark the file as being a text file with a custom encoding:

```
    *.txt    text working-tree-encoding=windows-1252
```

As far as I can tell, this approach cover all the complains listed above and works fine both on the command line and in the GUI. Unfortunately, there is a major caveat: It only works for files which were **created** after this attribute got set. With files created before I added this attribute, Git will display a change (from "unknown characters" to windows-1252) for every file which contains these unencoded characters. Also, after cloning the repository, it will complain that it "failed to encode 'a.txt' from UTF-8 to windows-1252". It seems the file actually got cloned correctly (byte-for-byte match against the original), but it still shows differences. Basically, I would have to commit every file with "unknown characters" to re-encode it to UTF-8 in the repository, which would cause hell with my history and pretty much make Blame unusable.

It seems that a realistic approach might be to use something like `git filter-branch`, but for the whole repository (is there anything like that?) to convert all existing files to UTF-8 **and** add the attribute to the very first commit, but I am worried about doing something this massive. Also, I expect that I would lose the prior commit IDs, which would be unfortunate (I stamp my executables with commit IDs to easily locate the version from which they were built).

---

Is there any way of overcoming the drawbacks of the methods described, or is there another method which would not be vulnerable to them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the right track by using the `working-tree-encoding`, but there's one more step you need.

In the same commit where you create the `.gitattributes` file, run `git add --renormalize .`, which will take all the working tree files and filter them according to the specified encoding.  Then you'll want to commit all of the changed files and the `.gitattributes` file in the same commit, and thereafter they'll be stored in the repo as UTF-8 but be Windows-1252 in your working tree.

This does have the downside that `git blame` will have to jump back beyond that commit, but you can specify `--ignore-rev` or `--ignore-revs-file` (or the config option `blame.ignoreRevsFile`) to ignore that revision, and everything will work.

Comment: That blame.ignoreRevsFile looks like a great solution, actually, even for some past mass-changes. I will need to perform some experiments here, but I think this could well be the way to go. Thanks! Once I get it done, I will mark the answer as the solution.

Comment: Also, there's the `merge.renormalize` config setting which causes all such transformations to be rerun with the current settings before running merges.